# /etc/hosts not working

Tags: server, dns, hosts

I populated `/etc/hosts` with device names and IP addresses.  For example:

```
chassisOne     10.0.0.1
chassisTwo     10.0.0.2
.
.
.
etcetera.
```

I am able to ping the IP address of both `chassisOne` and `chassisTwo`.  Pinging the hostname returns:

```
ping: unknown host chassisOne
```

My nsswitch.conf file is:

```
host:   files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 39):

From [`man hosts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html):

> This manual page describes the format of the /etc/hosts file.  This file is a simple text file that associates IP addresses with hostnames, one line per IP address.  For each host a single lineshould be present with the following information:
>
> ```
> IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
> ```

Thus,

```
chassisOne     10.0.0.1
```

is wrong.

It should be

```
10.0.0.1 chassisOne
```

Comment: Oh Lord ... ...I made a noob mistake!  Thank you.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted, so it doesn't pop up again in a year:)

Comment: Working on it.  Looking for the "Accepted" button.  :)

Comment: @DaleSmith It is the little check mark next to this answer here below the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: @Dale-smith:  the button (check-mark shaped) probably appeared now, next to this answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing it in the wrong order, the `ip` is supposed to go before the `domain`.

Try using this instead:

```
10.0.0.1 facebook.com
10.0.0.2 google.com
```

Then when you navigate to `facebook.com` or `google.com` on your browser, it'll display the following error:

[image: Firefox Error Screen]

Good luck.

Comment: Note that there's no wildcard matching. Thus, `facebook.com` will *not* match `www.facebook.com

Comment: @vidarlo I know, that screenshot was from an old example.